# Motivation because or that?

Tags: grammar, collocation

Which is correct, "because" or "that"?

> My motivation for doing things is because…

or

> My motivation for doing things is that…

I know to use "that" with "reason": "My reason is that..." But I'm not sure about whether "that" or "because" is correct with "motivation."

Answer (score 1):

I personally don't like sentences that are phrased as "The reason ____ is because ____." You'll find that your writing flows better if you remove the excess and just cut to the chase:

> I do these things because [reasons]

The word "because" already implies there is a "reason" or explanation for what you've already stated, so there's no use to precede the explanation with "My reason" or "My motivation".

Answer (score 0):

"My motivation for doing this is/was..." - without that or because.

> Part of my motivation for writing this piece was to pass along some of what I've learned. ([The Atlantic](http://www.theatlantic.com/doc/200602u/introverts))

See [here](http://fraze.it/n_search.jsp?hardm=1&t=0&l=0&p=3&q=my%20motivation) for many more examples.

Alternatively, you could say:

> I am motivated to do things because...

Comment: Thank you for that link. I did see this sentence there, using "that": My motivation as the character was that he was driven to save her life.